# Need Help on htaccess Redirection

Tags: .htaccess, vbulletin, mod-alias

Need help to make htaccess.
I use 2 domains: abc.domain1.com and domain2.com.
the htaccess will be in domain2.com.
i want to use it for vbulletin shorturl.

The idea are;

1. redirect `domain2.com/[numbers]` (example= `domain2.com/678`)
   to `abc.domain1.com/threads/[same numbers]` (example = `abc.domain1.com/threads/678`)
2. redirect `domain2.com/a[numbers]` (example= `domain2.com/a1234`)
   to `abc.domain1.com/forums/[same numbers]` (example = `abc.domain1.com/forums/1234`)

i tried for the case 1, is works with:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(.*) https://abc.domain1.com/threads/$1
```

but it doesn't work for case 2. i tried

```
RedirectMatch ^/f(.*) https://abc.domain1.com/forums/$1
```

but it gives me /threads/f[numbers]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If your question has been resolved, please accept an answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that was the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `/f1234` matches `^/(.*)` and it's being redirected to `https://abc.domain1.com/threads/f1234`.

Reverse the `RedirectMatch` lines, so that the more specific redirect is toward the top, and the "catch all" is at the very bottom:

```
RedirectMatch ^/f(.*) https://abc.domain1.com/forums/$1
RedirectMatch ^/(.*) https://abc.domain1.com/threads/$1
```

Comment: it's shame, I didn't think about that lines. thank you very much! what a life saver! xD

Answer (score 1):

You could also resolve this by being more specific with the regex. If you only want to match numbers then you should be doing just that and matching just numbers. For example:

```
RedirectMatch ^/(\d*)$ https://abc.domain1.com/threads/$1
RedirectMatch ^/f(\d*)$ https://abc.domain1.com/forums/$1
```

The shorthand character class `\d` matches the digits 0-9 only. And the trailing end-of-string anchor (`$`) ensures no other characters follow in the URL-path.

As per your original directives, this also matches when no number at all is given. eg. `/` and `/f` only. Is that the intention?

Comment: yes. thank you for your answer. it gives me insight the alternative way how to do it. this question is also solved already by rearrange the priority line like what @amphetamachine answer above.